# Scale Azure Service Bus through Powershell or API

Tags: azure, azureservicebus

I want to create a new Serviec Bus on Azure and then scale it up by using automation script.

Right now I can  create the service bus successfully by powershell cmdlet

`New-AzureSBNamespace -Name $Namespace -Location $Location -CreateACSNamespace $CreateACSNamespace -NamespaceType Messaging`

But I can't find any cmdlet or azure management API to scale its capacity.

After installing WindowsAzure.ServiceBus via nuget I found this class

`new Microsoft.ServiceBus.Management.MessagingSKUPlan(){SKU=2, SelectedEventHubUnit = 20 };`

But I don't know how to use it to scale the service bus

I've found an end point https://manage.windowsazure.com/ServiceBus/UpdateMessagingSKUPlan 
that used by http://manage.windowsazure.net to scale the service bus, but it's using http cookie for authentication which is hard to implement from Powershell normal authentication that using MS certificate.
[image: Scale Service Bus from Azure Management Portal]

My question is is there any way to scale the azure service bus from Powershell or an api?
If not, is there any idea how to call https://manage.windowsazure.com/ServiceBus/UpdateMessagingSKUPlan api from my automation script?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ThroughPut units is a Namespace level setting and will require a REST API call to the Azure Management endpoint. This requires two steps:

1. First do a GET on NS to get the existing NamespaceSKUPlan
   Request Uri format: `https://management.core.windows.net/<subscriptipn id>/services/ServiceBus/Namespaces/<namespaceName>/MessagingPlan`
2. Then perform a rest PUT operation on the same Uri stuffing in this properties:
   `<NamespaceSKUPlan xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/netservices/2010/10/servicebus/connect" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
           <SKU>{1 or 2}</SKU>
           <SelectedEventHubUnit>{1 - 20}</SelectedEventHubUnit>
           <Revision>{value from previous GET}</Revision>
       </NamespaceSKUPlan>`

Comment: Is there any documentation for this? I wasnt able to find it here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/servicebus/namespaces

Answer (score 1):

See

```
Set-AzureRmServiceBusNamespace -SkuCapacity 2 -ResourceGroupName <busName>
```